# Java has .class file which is the executable file/ binary file. Same way what is it for Python or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

In java .class files hide the actual source code and can only be executed. Am new to Python and JavaScript languages, how is source code protected in these languages? Do they also have something similar to .class files where in the source code isn't visible ?

Comment: `.class` files are not intended as a source code protection mechanism.

Comment: `.class` files are [trivial to decompile](http://www.javadecompilers.com/), so what is your actual question? The only way to hide source code is not to distribute it (i.e. offer it as a service). Not possible for client side Javascript of course.

Comment: to protect Python/Java code convert it to web page and deploy on some server. And then users can use it but they don't have access to files with code. With JavaScript you can't hide code.

Answer (score 1):

Python's equivalent to Java's `.class` file is the `.pyc` file. But this is even easier to decompile (translate back into Python) than `.class` files are. Javascript is distributed as Javascript, not compiled. Although it is often minified for performance.

The way you protect source code is with a license and copyright law. You may be looking for code obfuscators, but this will only deter casual hackers, and will only slow down someone determined. Even big-budget games with advanced DRM get cracked pretty quickly these days.

Comment: Note that copyright and license are two distinct things. The first (at least in the US) is granted automatically to the author or his/her employer. You typically need to pick one for the second.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making quite a bit of confusion, here.

First of all, `.class` files are not for "code protection" (we will get to what this means later), but compiled files which will be executed. You, simply put, cannot execute `.java` files, they have to be compiled in `.class` files. This is because Java is compiled to Bytecode (the machine language for the Java Virtual Machine), which is executed by the JVM. Both Javascript and Python can be executed without being compiled (there is Javascript/Python interpreter which runs the `.js` or `.py` files directly). There are some intermediate files in Python, with the `pyc` extension, which are alike the `.class` files, but, again, they are not good for protecting your code.

Now, if you want somebody to be able to execute your code without being able to read it, you have to keep in mind two things:

1. Decompilers/deobfuscators and so exist and are very good at their job;
2. While, in Java, the JVM executes compiled code, Python's and Javascript's interpreters execute the code as you write it;

You can try to obfuscate the code, but anybody will be able to deobfuscate it with the right tool. Does this mean that you Python code is less protected than your Java code? No, you can decompile `.class` and `.jar` files to read the source code (in fact, it is automatically done in IntelliJ Idea every time you navigate to the implementation of a library class or method).

So, if you want people to use your software but don't want them to copy it, you have two ways:

1. Do not distribute the software and go the SaaS way;
2. Find a good lawyer and ask their advice about how to protect you product according to local law;

Comment: You explained it very well. Thank you.